# replace canvas in html element

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

i'm creating table with pictures draw in canvas.
Ivery canva is in defferent div, where every div has different id.

i'm getting div by id and append there canvas:

```
    thumbnail(video, canvaId) {
  const canvasThumbnail = document.createElement('canvas')
  const cth = canvasThumbnail.getContext('2d')

  const data = video.slice(8)
  this.imgToHTML(data, e => {
    const drawingThumbnail = new Image()
    drawingThumbnail.src = e.target.result
    drawingThumbnail.onload = function () {
      canvasThumbnail.width = 300
      canvasThumbnail.height = 190
      cth.drawImage(drawingThumbnail, 0, 0)
      document.getElementById(canvaId).appendChild(canvasThumbnail)
    }
  })
},
```

Problem which i have is that sometimes i receive different picture for this same "id" and i should replace canvas in specific "id".
I was trying different methods (removeChild, replaceWith) but still can't work.

Can you help me, how to replace canvas in element with specific id?

Comment: Are you using Vue, or is that a mis-tag? In general, you shouldn't mix Vue with direct DOM manipulations like `document.createElement()`, instead opting for solutions that use the framework itself (when possible at least).

Comment: Show the Vue template that contains these `div`s and their IDs. And show how `thumbnail()` is called.